# security access_control: specific return (json) if ajax

Tags: symfony

I'm using access_control (securiry.yml) for control access on my pages. Like that:

```
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

If a not connected user try to access, he will be redirected. Ok, it's nice.
But some url can be used with Ajax. And i would like access_control return a json data in this case (not connected).
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own `AuthenticationHandler` which will implement two interfaces below:

```
class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, 
                                       AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
```

In that handler you should define two methods `onAuthenticationFailure()` and `onAuthenticationSuccess()`

Inside them just check if `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()`

```
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        ...
        return new Response($json);
    } else {
        ...
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

Don't forget also to set your listener in `security.yml`

```
firewalls:
    main:
        ....
        your_form_login:
            ...
            failure_handler: your.authentication_handler
            success_handler: your.authentication_handler
```

Comment: These actions are not only used on login form submission ?

Comment: `onAuthenticationXXX` are usually called when route `_check` is hit

Comment: Okay, nice, i will try soon =)